# Showing that $n^{1/4}(1-(1-n^{-1/4})^x) \ge \epsilon \cdot x$

Tags: calculus

Show that there exist $\epsilon > 0$ and integer $n_0 > 0$ such that for every $n \ge n_0$ and positive integer $x \le n^{1/4}$ we have $$n^{1/4}(1-(1-n^{-1/4})^x) \ge \epsilon \cdot x$$

I managed to show that this holds for specific values of $x$ such as $1$ or $n^{1/4}$, but how can we show it for every $x$?

Answer (score 0):

Let’s simplify this a bit by introducing $z=n^\frac14$.

The derivative of

$$
f(x)=z\left(1-\left(1-z^{-1}\right)^x\right) - \epsilon \cdot x
$$

is

$$
f'(x)=-z\log\left(1-z^{-1}\right)\left(1-z^{-1}\right)^x - \epsilon\;.
$$

This is a monotonically decreasing function with a single zero at

$$x_0=\frac{\log\frac\epsilon{-z\log\left(1-z^{-1}\right)}}{\log\left(1-z^{-1}\right)}\;.
$$

For large $n$ this is asymptotic to $-z\log\epsilon$. Thus for $\epsilon=\mathrm e^{-2}$ and sufficiently large $n$ the function $f(x)$ has a single maximum at $x_0\approx 2z$ and thus takes its lowest value in the interval $[0,z]$ at $0$. Since $f(0)=0$, $f$ is non-negative throughout this interval, and hence the inequality is fulfilled.